# Help me understand this 4-wire RTD circuit

Tags: sensor, thermistor, wheatstone-bridge, rtd, instrumentation

This circuit is a kelvin connection of 4-wire RTD. Resistance element is a 4-wire RTD (PT100).
Can anyone tell me what can be the values of the resistors in the arms (RH)? And can anyone explain the working and balance equations?

What should be the value of "r"? When bridge will balance? Please give me the equations for this circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

RH should be as high as possible. All the resistors marked RH are the same value.

S should be chosen so that S/(RH+RT) gives the appropriate current through the RTD for the
desired sensitivity and self-heating (engineering trade-off).

R should be equal to RT at the temperature of most interest (where the bridge will be balanced, ignoring leadwire resistance).

Comment: if i connect a current source of 1mA as a Excitation, then what will be the equations for output voltage? i want equation, can u please give me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is just a resistor network, you should be able to use elementary circuit analysis.

Comment: in this way if i connect then lead resistance will be compensated right?

Comment: First order compensated only. This kind of passive network can *never* exactly compensate for leadwire resistance changes.

Comment: like how we have a equation for output voltage for wheatStone bridge , like that i wanted an equation for calculating output voltage Equation.

Comment: what means First order Compensated?

Comment: if m applying "Iex" as excitation current from a constant current source , then , output will be equal to 
Vout= (Iex * RT) - (Iex * R)
 is above equation proper?

Comment: @Priyanka It'd be a good idea to perform some basic 'bridge network' [simulations](https://www.circuitlab.com), it'll help you see further.

Comment: @Priyanka   Suppose RH is 1M ohm and S is 2000V, then IRTD is about 1mA (essentially constant). Then if R = Rt0, the bridge output is very close to (Rt - Rt0) * 1mA. You can work out the real situation when S is more reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you have drawn does not give a balanced output when the power feeds to the RTD have any series resistance - this is the whole idea about having the two extra connections.

For example: Excitation voltage is 10V and all RH values are 1k ohm. RTD and R are 100 ohm. With no lead resistance, the bridge is balanced. Put 10 ohms in each lead and the bridge output is offset by about 4mV: -

[image]

If you think about it this has to be the case - the resistor marked R in your circuit (R2 in mine) shares a common point with the RTD (R1 in mine) due to the cross connection and this, in effect bypasses one of the lead resistors. What is left is a mismatch because of the remaining lead resistor (R3).

This does not produce what you want - the current through R5 will not equal the current through R6 when RTD = R in the presence of lead resistance.

Comment: So, the two extra leads allow you to 1) feed with a constant current while measuring voltage, or 2) use the extra wires as senses to maintain constant (and desired) excitation voltage??

Comment: hey andy, does your circuit gives accurate output? as compared to mine?
and in ur circuit u have mentioned some values like 4.716 ,4.763..i dint get that ..what are those values?

Comment: @Andy aka
so what is the solution for the remaining Lead (R3)?

Comment: hey andy , if i connect a resister in Series with R6, whos resistance approx equals lead resistance (r3) , then will it compensate for that R3 in your ckt?

Comment: @priyanka ive made an error in my circuit that I can't correct until Thursday so bear with me .I forgot to put a ten ohm resistor on one wire

Comment: @Scott Seidman Yes, that's the general way to deal with a Kelvin connection RTD. Two wires are "force" (fed from a very high impedance current source) and two wires are "sense" (measured by a differential amplifier with high input impedance. That completely cancels out leadwire resistance if the current source and amplifier are perfect (in practice it's not hard to make them good enough they are not the long pole in the tent).